# Android QR code generation with zxing library not working

Tags: android, qr-code, zxing

Hi I am developing small android application in which I want to include Qr code functionality.
I downloaded zxing-2.1  and with the help of android project inside it and core.jar i create android library for android project. I created one android project and include that library into my android project.

But when i tried to create one Qr code it gives me following error:

```
// I tried to generate Qr code in following ways.
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.qr_imageView);
    String qrData = "nilkash";
    int qrCodeDimention = 500;

    QRCodeEncoder qrCodeEncoder = new QRCodeEncoder(qrData, null,
            Contents.Type.TEXT, BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE.toString(), qrCodeDimention);

    try {
        Bitmap bitmap = qrCodeEncoder.encodeAsBitmap();
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    } catch (WriterException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

But It not recognizing QRCodeEncoder class. What i am doing wrong? Need help to generate Qr-codes with zxing library. Thank you.

Comment: where is your error.?

Comment: It gives me error for QRCOdeEncoder `QRCodeEncoder cannot be resolved to a type`

Comment: @nilkash how u resolved i m getting error after adding class the method format(String) is undefined for the type Formatter

Answer (score 0):

You didn't put `core.jar` in your project's `libs/` folder. This is nothing to do with the library.

EDIT: Oops, no, `QRCodeEncoder` is actually a class in `android/`, my fault. It won't help to use `core.jar`. The problem is still of course that you're trying to use a class without making it accessible to your project. This is not a library class though, but part of the app. You can reuse the source for this class in your app though, including copying it if that's easiest.

Comment: that mean i have to put core.java into my main android project not in library project ?

Comment: Now I added core.jar file in libs folder of both project i.e. android app project and library project. still it giving problem. Need help. thank you for replay.

Comment: hi @Sean Owen I downloaded latest zxing library. But its core folder not containing .jar file. How to build or how to generate that .jar file. Need help. Thank you for help

Comment: I ran ant in my core folder but it giving some snapshot missing error. how to remove this error.

Comment: Yes, if you want to use a library in an Android app, the simplest thing is to put the .jar file in `libs/`. I don't know what library project you mean. Please read documentation: https://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/GettingStarted

Comment: Than you for replay sir. I downloaded latest zxing project but it not containing core.jar file. so how to obtain that, I tried to generate that by running `ant` in core folder but it gives me some snapshot missing error. how to get that core.jar file. need help. Thank you

Comment: As I said: read the documentation before you ask further. code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/GettingStarted

Comment: Oh come on, Sean! The lib does not contain the class, period! Can't you just be kind enough to give us a short precise answer (the whole point of StackOverflow, at least this is exactly how it operates) instead of pointing to some lengthy documentation, which anyway has moved to GitHub (your links are no longer valid)?

Comment: Hey @Yar, I'll update the links if I can. This class is actually in `android/`, which is my fault for not reading carefully. I will update the reply. I still think this is a case where the OP should have done minimal homework; it's trivial to locate this class.

Comment: Note, project docs are now at : https://github.com/zxing/zxing/wiki/Getting-Started-Developing

Answer (score 0):

You can find core.jar in following link http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/zxing/core/2.2/

Comment: QRCodeEncoder still cannot be found in core-2.2.jar  nor core-3.1.0.jar

Answer (score 0):

QRCodeEncoder and Contents can be found here:

http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/09/android-generate-qr-code-using-zxing.html